# Crop and save image (UIElement) in Windows Store App using c# with

Tags: c#, .net, image, windows-store-apps, crop

I already can take a print screen from the actual content of my application.
I choose az UIElement (e.g. a grid), and I render it into a bmp file.

But how can I crop this image as i feel?
The code is below works, just the cropping missing. I work for windows 8.1.

```
public async void SaveVisualElementToFile(UIElement element, StorageFile file)
    {
        var renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
        await renderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync(element);
        var pixels = await renderTargetBitmap.GetPixelsAsync();

        using (IRandomAccessStream stream = await 
               file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
        {
            var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(
                                              BitmapEncoder.JpegEncoderId, stream);
            byte[] bytes = pixels.ToArray();
            encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
                                 BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore,
                                 (uint)renderTargetBitmap.PixelWidth, 
                                 (uint)renderTargetBitmap.PixelHeight,
                                 96, 96, bytes);

            await encoder.FlushAsync();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this. There's the [traditional way](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/OneCode/OneCode-How-to-crop-an-image-in-Windows-Store-Application) as espoused by MSFT themself. You can also use some extensions such as [WinRTXamlToolkit](http://WinRTXamlToolkit.codeplex.com) and [WriteableBitmapEx](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com). The latter two make it quite easy. Check in their source codes on Codeplex for their sample applications, which will have samples for how to use cropping.

Comment: Yaeh, yestoday I make it with WriteableBitmapEx, so thnaks :)